# Error when fitting KNN model

Tags: r, knn

I was going to fit a knn model with faithful data in R. My code is like this:

```
smp_size <- floor(0.5 * nrow(faithful))
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(faithful)), size = smp_size)
train_data = faithful[train_ind, ]
test_data = faithful[-train_ind, ]

pred = FNN::knn.reg(train = train_data[,1], 
                  test = test_data[,1], 
                  y = train_data[,2], k = 5)$pred
```

The faithful data only has 2 columns. I met this error "Error in get.knnx(train, test, k, algorithm) : Number of columns must be same!."

I don't understand why the error will come up because the columns of train and test data are the same.

Thanks first for answering my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?knn.reg` says that `train`/`test` has to be data frame or matrix. But in your case you just have one independent variable so when you do `str(train_data[,1])` it is no more a data frame. So the solution is to use `as.data.frame` with train & test parameters in `knn.reg`.

Another important point is that you need to first 'normalize' your data before you run KNN. May be you can try below snippet as a minor improvement to your code:

```r
library('FNN')
set.seed(123)

#normalize data
X = scale(faithful[, -ncol(faithful)])
y = faithful[, ncol(faithful)]

#split data into train & test
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(faithful)), floor(0.7 * nrow(faithful)))
test_ind <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(faithful)), train_ind)

#run KNN model
knn_model <- knn.reg(train = as.data.frame(X[train_ind,]), 
                     test = as.data.frame(X[test_ind,]), 
                     y = y[train_ind], 
                     k = 5)
pred = knn_model$pred
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For FNN::knn.reg, the **test** and **y** must be data-frames. Just a minor modification to the last statement.

```
pred = FNN::knn.reg(train = train_data[,1], 
                    test = test_data[1], 
                    y = train_data[2], k = 5)$pred
```